# Linux bash interruptions

Tags: bash, cgi, ipc, gpio

I'm trying to put something together that when it receives an event, say and HTTP request to apache cgi-bin it would generate a "flag" that another script picks up and execute some code?

another "interrupt" will be a push button where im getting most of the problems, becuase i want to put that in a loop, if I source that script then that sourcing script will halt because of the loop, if i use name pipes it will halt as well waiting for data...

i've been triying named pipes, sourcing scripts and all sorts of things but i dont manage to get something consistent, i was wondering thinking on using other IPC options, like signals, shared memory and thoose kind of things.

to start with does anyone have any experience with this, know any resources and if it's even possible.

Comment: What kind of a flag do you need to pass to the other script, just a "ping" or do you need information about the request? Is the other script already running or does it have to be started? How do you put a push button in a loop? Sounds quite vague.

Comment: Thanks, To start with a flag, just a ping would be enought probably, i could then create differente flags for differente requests... the sourcing script would be running it doesnt need to be started when event happened, altought that would interesting probably, to be honest haven't tought on an scenario when was not runnin would probably strart from boot... about the push button, a loogp reading the status of a GPIO input pin as what i want to do is an event when the button has been pushed, so im thinking in a short of function just doing that reading that input pin from GPIO - continue...

Comment: And if detects a "button pressed event" and creating that flag for the "main" script to know that button has been pressed and dont loose that event and interrupt of modify the flow of the script... any help is most appreciated please let me know if im still not explaining my self. -  Thanks.

Comment: For a "ping" you can use a signal, for example `USR1`, but if you plan to send more than a handful of different flags you'll run out of signals. A messaging library such as zeromq or queue such as beanstalkd could be more appropriate.

Comment: With a push button you mean a hardware button on an embedded device? Which is the "main" script? The flow in which script has to be modified?

Comment: Yes, by button i mean a hardware button, physically connected to a GPIO on the board running linux, so on the electronics/electric side of things... im working with a Pi maybe that has a GPIO header. the main script is the one that received the flag from a secondary script that it's doing the background scanning of a change on a physical pin. I'm looking deeper in to signal now and how to alert a parent from a child short of thing. this looks appropiate for me: [link](http://www.engineersgarage.com/embedded/raspberry-pi/how-to-use-signal-values-and-messages-to-read-multiple-inputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to work at a kernel level using Inter-process Communications socket or also known as domain sockets